# How to set MPEG-4 as the default video output container?

Tags: rendering, output

Matroska is the default one. Is it possible to change this to MPEG-4 by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup:

1. Make a new file
2. Change the default video output container to MPEG-4
3. File -> Defaults -> Save Startup File

This will save anything you changed in the file as the default! (So next time you create a new project, the default video output container will be MPEG-4, every time!)

Comment: Thank you, it's rather a workaround but it helps. The Container jumps back to Matroska as soon as you choose another File format. So I will have to change it every time I jump back and forth between PNG and FFmpeg Video.